# How do I connect to a Telnet Server in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, telnet

I am having my OJT and my current task is to do an FTP Client Server connecting to a telnet Server. This is my first time doing this kind of a program. Any idea how I can do this in c# windows app? how do i establish a connection to telnet with completeauthentications? Are their any open source libraries to help me do this? Any help with this will be very much appreciated. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: There is another [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390188/c-sharp-telnet-library) on this topic that answers it very well.

The most popular strategy seem to involve using the System.Net.Sockets class

These two sites both have code samples and describe opening a connection and reading data:
[C# Help - TELNET Client](https://web.archive.org/web/20091204074321/http://www.csharphelp.com:80/archives/archive239.html)

[C# and Telnet- Not as painful as it sounds](https://web.archive.org/web/20200731105130/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/bigpapa/archive/2007/10/08/C-2.0-and-Telnet---Not-As-Painful-As-It.aspx)

But, if you want to go the open source route, there is a project called [.NET Telnet](https://dotnettelnet.sourceforge.net/) which provides an open source library to help with telnet interactions.

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading on the [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) class, and then search for example code. If you need to implement a [`Telnet`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) client you should understand the good old [RFC 854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854).

[`FTP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) is just a bunch of other RFCs, you can start with [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959).

Both Telnet and FTP clients are directly implementable with `TcpClient`.