# Executing commands by using Telnet in C#

Tags: c#, command, telnet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Telnet Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390188/c-sharp-telnet-library)

I wish to do **telnet** programatically using C# so that once I establish the connection to the server, I can execute the commands like *ls, ls -l, mv, rm.. etc* on the server.

Is it possible? Are there classes in C# for this purpose similar to the classes for FTP (FtpWebRequest)? If yes, please direct me to the right approach.

When I execute *ls*, I need the list generated on server to be sent to the client i.e. windows machine in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, here you have a telnet library
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MinimalisticTelnet.aspx

Comment: Need to know one thing from the Minimalistic Telnet app. I went and debugged to understand the code. Understood most of it.. but have a doubt in one area i.e the user command (like ls) is converted to bytes and written on the socket stream (tcpSocket.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length)) and then read byte by byte. I would like to know where is the command actually executed?? Little confused here..