# How to write c# console app that behave like the telnet command on cmd windows?

Tags: c#, .net, telnet

I want to programmatically sending (and processing the response) message. Instead of open cmd and type in the command manually:

1. connecting to the server by using command `telnet [server_address] [port_number]`
2. send a message
3. processing the response and send a following message
4. repeat step 3 ...

How can I achieve this by using c#?

Comment: Based on a description you need regular console application. What exactly you want to automate?

Comment: This is a very vague question. What do you mean by "behave like the telnet command"? In what way should it behave like the telnet command? What do you want your application to actually *do*?

Comment: Probably you looking for smtng like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359850/executing-commands-by-using-telnet-in-c-sharp

Comment: so, basically you wish for an application that listen to a certain port and do something once someone send it a message..?

Comment: @BagusTesa I was given a server that I can connect to and send/receive message using telnet. I want to automate the process instead of manually typing the command. I don't know how telnet works, that why I can't tell exactly what I need.

Comment: @vladimirpanf that is what I need, if you post your comment as an answer, I can vote for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telnet library url: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MinimalisticTelnet.aspx

Previous thread: [Executing commands by using Telnet in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359850/executing-commands-by-using-telnet-in-c-sharp)

Cheers.