# Executing telnet Command through CMD using c# windows form

Tags: c#

I want to ask you how to execute the Telnet command through cmd using c#.
I am able to do (ping,tracert) but unable to do Telnet.

The objective of my app is to check the network connectivity of the servers.
So i am trying to ping,telnet and tracert the server ip.
But i am stuck with telenet ..
The error cmd is showing "'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
I have enabled the telnet client from add and remove program steps.

My code for executing telnet is

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
       new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/k " + telnet 192.168.74.74 21;

procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
// Do not create the black window.
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
// Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Appreciate all the comments kindly please help..
Waiting for the solution.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390188/c-sharp-telnet-library

Comment: Why not call `telnet.exe` directly? There is also a syntax error for the code you pasted into your question. The `procStartInfo` line will not compile.

Comment: My major objective is to check the status of server,

Comment: we execute telnet ip port no and chek the status of the server and take a snapshot of cmd and sent them, so thats why i am executing it threw process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `Process.Start` is the wrong way to do this.

You can use the [`Ping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to do a ping, and the [`Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to do some communication with the Telnet server (maybe something like [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/57a15405-6ba3-4522-a4ac-c3913215c7a2/using-tcpclient-to-do-a-telnet-session?forum=netfxnetcom)). In that way you don't have to use `Process.Start` and go through all the output reading and parsing problems.

**Concerning your actual problem:** I think it is related to 32-64 bit stuff. If your program runs in 32 bit mode on a 64 bit machine, the software can't find `telnet`. If you uncheck the `Prefer 32 bit` in the `Project Properties > Build`, it finds the file and the program works.

Comment: actually i want to write in cmd and check the hops whether its is failing or connecting to the required ip, and then take a snapshot of cmd.

Comment: @PatrickHofman  OP says " I have enabled the telnet client from add and remove program steps." Also there is no confirmation that OP can run telnet from CMD directly...

Comment: Patrick Hofman-Thank You so much, you have given the exact solution the problem. Cheers keep on helping Sir.!!!

Comment: @PatrickHofman Do you know to enable such setting from the command line?

Comment: What setting @william?

Comment: @PatrickHofman `Project Properties > Build` I'm trying to do something similar here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341057/windows-automate-telnet?noredirect=1#comment52557392_32341057

Comment: What about using [`TcpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx)? See the sample included there.