# Set negotiation mode on Plink

Tags: .net, telnet, putty, plink

I am trying open a TelNet Connection using PLink

My connection string is: `plink.exe -telnet -P <Port Number> <IP Address>`

Although the connection is opened due to the firewall on the other side I can't login without changing the negotiation mode to passive

Here is how it's changed using Putty

[image: Putty Configuration, Negotiation mode]

I was an unable to find a documentation that explained how this can be done using PLink

PLink will eventually be used by a .net program and will log events passed through the connection. So I'm looking for a way to duplicate what Putty does either with PLink or with a .net 4.5 TelNet Nugget package

Comment: Do not launch external application to implement Telnet. Use .NET Telnet library. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/390188/850848

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have sees that, but I couldn't find it in nugget

Comment: So download project source code.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl downloaded the source code, still have the same problem with the negotiation mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not launch external application to implement Telnet. Use some .NET Telnet library.

See [C# Telnet Library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/390188/850848).

---

If you want to use Plink anyway:

Plink does not allow you to set most options using command-line.

What you can do it to create ad-hoc temporary stored settings in Windows registry and have Plin use that using [`-load` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-load).

For your needs you need to create keys like:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\passive_telnet]
"HostName"="example.com"
"Protocol"="telnet"
"PortNumber"=dword:00000017
"PassiveTelnet"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: I ended up downloading the C# class you mentioned and doing some modifications to it