# Telnet is not recognized command when cmd.exe is started from Process.Start in C#

Tags: c#, cmd, telnet

I have already switch on the telnet option on control panel - program/features.
Though telnet worked fine manually, but when I run below from my C# library, I am getting this error :

> "'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file."

This is the code I use to start Telnet:

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/k telnet")
```

What makes the difference between this and running it from the command prompt manually and how do I overcome this difference?

Comment: Telnet is a *program*. You can start it just like you star cmd.exe or Word.exe. You don't need to start Cmd first. Just pass the path to telnet.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On installing **Telnet Client** via **Control Panel - Programs and Features - Turn Windows features on or off** there is installed `telnet.exe` into directory `%SystemRoot%\System32`.

The directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` is for 64-bit applications on 64-bit Windows. Therefore the installed executable `telnet.exe` is also the 64-bit version. This directory contains also the 64-bit version of `cmd.exe`.

System environment variable **PATH** contains `%SystemRoot%\System32` which is responsible for finding `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` and `%SystemRoot%\System32\telnet.exe` when being executed without file extension and without path.

But there is additionally the directory `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` for 32-bit applications containing the 32-bit versions of the executables.

Microsoft explains with the documentation pages [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details) and [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) how a file system access to `%SystemRoot%\System32` by a 32-bit application is redirected automatically to `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64`.

There is no 32-bit version of `telnet.exe` installed into `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` on installing **Telnet Client**.

So what happens on:

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/k telnet")
```

When the C# library is compiled as 64-bit library used by a 64-bit application, 64-bit Windows finds and starts `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` which finds and then starts `%SystemRoot%\System32\telnet.exe`.

But when the C# library is compiled as 32-bit library used by a 32-bit application, 64-bit Windows finds and starts via file system redirector `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` which cannot find `telnet.*` with a file extension listed in environment variable **PATHEXT** in current directory or any directory of environment variable **PATH** because there is no file `telnet.exe` in directory `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64`.

---

The best solution is definitely to use a static (or dynamic) telnet library in the C# library to be independent on `telnet.exe` as suggested by [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos). In my point of view it is a shame for every C# programmer using external executables via a process call for which C# code can be quite easily also written by the programmer. Using any world wide web search engine with the search term `C# telnet` returns lots of pages with solutions, for example [C# Telnet Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390188/) on Stack Overflow.

Of course it is also possible to get first value of environment variable **SystemRoot** using [GetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getenvironmentvariable) method to get path to Windows directory, or even better using [GetWindowsDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getwindowsdirectorya) or [GetSystemWindowsDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getwindowsdirectoryw) method.

Then concatenate this string value with `"\\System32\\telnet.exe"` to a new string and check if the file with that full path exists using [File.Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists) method. If that file exists on 32-bit Windows with 32-bit version of `telnet.exe` installed if C# application is also a 32-bit application or on 64-bit Windows with 64-bit `telnet.exe` installed if C# application is a 64-bit application, then this file name with full path and file extension can be used in a process call.

Otherwise concatenate the Windows directory path with `"\\Sysnative\\telnet.exe"` and check if file with that full path exists. If this is true on 64-bit Windows with 64-bit version of `telnet.exe` installed if C# application is a 32-bit application, it would be possible to run from within 32-bit application the 64-bit telnet client executable using this path.

But if that fails also, `telnet.exe` is not installed at all which is the reason why usage of `telnet.exe` from within a C# code application is in general not advisable.

Honestly, I don't understand why to have code in a C# library which just starts a command process executing `telnet.exe` without options and therefore requiring user input and which keeps the command process running after telnet client session terminated. The C# library function can be replaced by a shortcut to `telnet.exe` on Windows desktop or in Windows start menu of the user.

Answer (score 3):

Telnet is a program, *always* installed in the system folder. Which also means, it's always in the path. You *don't* need to start `cmd.exe` in order to start `telnet.exe`. Just use

```
Process.Start("telnet.exe");
```

Use the `arguments` parameter to pass arguments to telnet itself, eg the host, log file etc:

```
Process.Start("telnet.exe","localhost 80 -f mylog.txt");
```

There other, probably better options.

**Use a Telnet Library**

You can use a Telnet library and connect to a server directly, eg using the [Telnet NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telnet/) :

```
using (Client client = new Client("localhost",80, new System.Threading.CancellationToken()))
{
    await client.WriteLine("abcd");
    string response = await client.ReadAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
```

**Use PowerShell**

Telnet is often used to test connectivity to a web server, not to actually send commands. In this case, you could use PowerShell's [Test-NetConnection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/nettcpip/test-netconnection) to receive diagnostics about the connection:

```
using System.Management.Automation;

var ps = PowerShell.Create()
                    .AddCommand("test-netconnection")
                    .AddArgument("localhost")
                    .AddParameter("CommonTCPPort", "HTTP");
var results = cmd.Invoke();
foreach (dynamic result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{result.TcpTestSucceeded} {result.SourceAddress}");
}
```

Make sure you add the correct Powershell NuGet package, [Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies/), not the unsupported and abandoned `System.Management.Automation` package

The advantage of PowerShell is that you can chain commands and scripts together just by adding more `AddComand`, `AddScript` calls. Each command will receive the output of the previous one. You could use `Import-CSV` to read a list of servers and ports from a file and pipe the output to `Test-NetConnection`

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis. The only issue I have is the redirection as mentioned by Mofi. Unless I can redirect, it always says telent is not recognized. \

Comment: Use a library then. You can't control `telnet.exe` the way you started it anyway - you'd have to redirect the input/output streams at least to be able to send commands